# compass returning 0 rows with “#” (hash character) in search query

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, compass-lucene

I am using compass based indexing on my project. Now in one of the scenario I have field values something like 'dummy#value'. So if I am trying to search with any of the value which contains '#' character, its returning 0 rows..

For e.g.

**DummyTable**

```
id   field_name
----------------
1    dummy#value
2    otherVal1
3    otherVal2
```

**Query**

```
+(+alias:DummyTable +field_name:dummy#value*) +(alias:DummyTable)
```

returning 0 rows, whereas

```
+(+alias:DummyTable +field_name:dummy*) +(alias:DummyTable)
```

returning 1 row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was required to annotate the field declaration as

**NOT_ANALYZED : (Index the property's value without using an Analyzer, so it can be searched)**

```
@SearchableProperty(index=Index.NOT_ANALYZED)
private String field_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think # is a special character so I'm surprised this isn't working for you. You could try escaping the character using `\#`.

Another option could be to surround the term in quotes

Good luck

Comment: thanks for your response... Tried with \# which doesn't work... With query : +(+alias:DummyTable +field_name:dummy"#"value*) +(alias:DummyTable) its returning all the records because of some auto indexed filed has value such as $/uid : DummyTable#74#, DummyTable#73# etc., that means its searching for all the indexed field whenever we surround any term with " " (double quotes)?

Comment: can you not surround the whole term in quotes i.e. "dummy#value"?